# JTable, Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

How do I get the code for the line that I edited using the JTable and its listeners?
 I'm doing this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

class TableListener implements TableModelListener {

       @Override
       public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
              if ( e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE ) {
                     System.out.println("Updating ...\n");
                     TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
                     String columnName = model.getColumnName(e.getColumn());
                     Object data = model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
                     System.out.println(Arrays.asList(data));
              }
       }


}
```

---

```
          model.addTableModelListener(new TableListener());
          CustomersList lista = new CustomersList();
          final JTable table = lista.getTable();
          table.setModel(model);
          table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
          lista.setVisible(true);
```

I just do not have, or know of no method that returns only the code myself, I also block cell editing in the code ..

Comment: Can you please clarify just what it is you're asking?  Perhaps it's me, but this: `How do I get the code for the line that I edited using the JTable and its listeners` and this: `I just do not have, or know of no method that returns only the code myself, I also block cell editing in the code ..` make no sense to me.

Comment: I'm still have no idea what you're asking. Sorry.

Comment: What code or id? Do you want to extract a specific part of the model from the table? like the ID of a row or something?

Comment: Yes .. id of a row, in this case .. is a customer code.

Comment: You're already doing that with your `TableModelEvent` object, e: `e.getFirstRow()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yes, but this getting after edited

The model does *not* track before/after values. If you want this information you need to do it yourself.

Or, you can use the [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) which does this for you.